# Android Connecting multiple devices with WiFi Direct

Tags: android, wifi, connection

Ok so I was wondering if a certain scenario is possible.

Lets say we have the following devices:

```
A -> Tablet
B -> IP Camera (or any arbitrary device that can connect to and/or get connections from other devices
C -> WiFi device emitting it's own network (this is NOT a router) for connections
```

Now is it possible to have my camera connect to my tablet and then my tablet to the other device so my tablet can communicate with both external device?

So the connection look something like this:

```
B->A->C
```

I can configure devices A and B to either connect to other devices or accept connections, device C is the only wildcard here, it is not configurable and emits is own network and the only way to communicate with it is to join that network.

What I am trying to do:

I have a wifi receiver that gets signals from a phone and converts them to analog signals to be used in RC vehicles (instead of an RC receiver, it is a wifi receiver).  I am developing an app which will control the RC vehicle through the wifi receiver as well as receive a live video stream from the IP camera that will display in my app, problem is the receiver emits it's own network and in order to use it I have to connect to it, and I do not see any routing functions on it so it doesn't look like I can connect the camera to the receiver and still get a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn is designed for peer to peer communication, and can be used to create virtual networks connecting through WIFI and Bluetooth. Depending on what camera you have it may be able to meet your needs. I have seen it working between a television and a Tablet. https://www.alljoyn.org/

Comment: Interesting, never heard of this I'll definitely take a look, I also updated my question to exactly what I am doing so that maybe it is more clear to people.